# How to insert div text to input field?

Tags: jquery, html

How to insert Div text to Input field using Jquery through id???

```
<div id="tmstatus>bla bla</div>

<input type="hidden" name="tm_name" >
```

any hint???

Comment: Here is a working example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofodij/2/edit)
(Note that I have changed input type to text from hidden so you can see the result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="tmstatus>bla bla</div>    
<input type="hidden" id="textBoxId" name="tm_name" >    

$("#textBoxId").val($('#tmstatus').text(););
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div_val = jQuery("#tmstatus").html();
jQuery("input[name='tm_name']").val(div_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

As my consideration try this

```
var my_txt = $('#tmstatus').text(); 
$("input[name='tm_name']").val(my_txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input[name="tm_name"]').val($('#tmstatus').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this exactly what you need. First you take away the input element and replace it with an empty span element:

```
<div id="tmstatus">bla bla</div>
<span id="input_holder"></span>
```

Then run this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get_val = document.getElementById('tmstatus').innerHTML;
    var element = '<input type="text" value="'+ get_val +'" name="tm_name" />';
    $("#input_holder").html(element);
});
```